# GCP: Allowing Public Ingress Web Traffic from the Load Balancer ONLY

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, load-balancing, firewall

*Disclaimers: I come from AWS background but relatively very new to GCP. I know there are a number of existing similar questions (e.g, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57355533/how-to-prevent-public-access-to-compute-engine-external-ip-address) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50795561/google-cloud-http-load-balancer-health-check-fails-without-an-external-ip) etc) but I still cannot get it work since the exact/detailed instructions are still missing. So please bear with me to ask this again.*

**My simple design:**

> **Public HTTP/S Traffic (Ingress)** >> GCP Load Balancer >> GCP Servers

GCP Load Balancer holds the SSL Cert. And then it uses Port 80 for downstream connections to the Servers. Therefore, LB to the Servers are just HTTP.

**My question:**

How do I prevent the incoming HTTP/S **Public** Traffic from reaching to the GCP Servers directly? Instead, only allow the Load Balancer (as well as it's Healthcheck Traffic)?

**What I tried so far:**

I went into Firewall Rules and removed the previously allowing rule of Ports 80/443 (Ingress Traffic) from `0.0.0.0/0`. And then, added (allowed) the External IP address of Load Balancer.

At this point, I simply expected the Public Traffic should be rejected but the Load Balancer's. But in reality, both seemed to be rejected. Nothing reached the Servers anymore. The Load Balancer's External IP wasn't seemed to be recognised.

Later I also noticed the "Healthchecks" were also not recognised anymore. Therefore Healthchecks couldn't reach to Servers and then failed. Hence the Instances were dropped by Load Balancer.

Please also note that: I cannot pursue the approach of simply removing the External IPs on the Servers. (Although many people say this would work.) But we still want to maintain the direct SSH accesses to the Servers (by not using a Bastion Instance). Therefore I still need the External IPs, on each and every Web Servers.

Any clear (and kind) instructions will be very much appreciated. Thank you all.

Comment: Just to confirm, you have created an ingress firewall rule allowing traffic from both `35.191.0.0/16` and `130.211.0.0/22` IP ranges targeted to your VM instances by tag, am I correct?

Comment: @LundinCast thank you. That was the case!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're able to setup HTTPS connectivity between your load balancer and your back-end servers while using [HTTP(S) load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https). To achieve this goal you should install HTTPS certificates on your back-end servers and configure web-servers to use them. If you decided to completely switch to HTTPS and disable HTTP on your back-end servers you should switch your health check from HTTP to HTTPS also.

**To make health check working again after removing default firewall rule** that allow connection from `0.0.0.0/0` to ports 80 and 443 you need to whitelist subnets `35.191.0.0/16` and `130.211.0.0/22` which are source IP ranges for health checks. You can find step by step instructions how to do it in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-checks#fw-rule). After that, access to your web servers still be restricted but your load balancer will be able to use health check and serve your customers.

Comment: Oh, all I've been missing was just that two `35.191.0.0/16` and `130.211.0.0/22` IPs! I thought we need to use the Load Balancer's actual External IP itself. But apparently not. After allowing those 2 and then removed the `0.0.0.0/0`, it all works! Thank you so much.